# Install Pinia with Quasar v2

Tags: npm, conflict, quasar-framework, state-management

I'm using Quasar v2, Vue 3 and I'm trying to install Pinia.
Whenever I try to run: `npm install pinia` or also `npm install pinia@next`,
it gives me this error:

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ui@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"3.1.5" from @quasar/app@3.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@quasar/app
npm ERR!     dev @quasar/app@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"3.1.5" from @vue/compiler-sfc@3.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc
npm ERR!     @vue/compiler-sfc@"3.1.5" from @quasar/app@3.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@quasar/app
npm ERR!       dev @quasar/app@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @vue/compiler-sfc@"^3.0.8" from vue-loader@16.4.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/vue-loader
npm ERR!       vue-loader@"16.4.1" from @quasar/app@3.0.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@quasar/app
npm ERR!         dev @quasar/app@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@vue/server-renderer, @vue/test-utils, vue-i18n, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! pinia@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@"^2.6.14 || ^3.2.0" from pinia@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/pinia
npm ERR!     pinia@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/gii/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Moreover, since I'm using Typescript, is there a way to configure it already with it via this initial npm command?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Pinia if you remove Vuex first.
Just delete Vuex from your `package.json` and then you are free to install Pinia.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem while installing pinia from npm having vuex configured in my vue3 app , after couple of try i uninstalled vuex and reinstalled pinia and then it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get everything installed and are not concerned about possibly running incompatible versions: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Beyond that, your options get much more involved. You can try updating everything and cross your fingers that all the most up-to-date versions are compatible with each other. You can downgrade dependencies that require newer versions of peer dependencies. And so on.